# Block by CORS policy for Laravel Nginx full stack

Tags: laravel, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, react-fullstack

I have a full-stack application created using Laravel. My project is separated into two parts: frontend and backend. When I deploy the project using Linux, Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04 server, it does not work.

It gives me this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://devapi.trial.com.my/api/v1/login'
> from origin 'http://159.138.83.48' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. xhr.js:160 POST https://devapi.trial.com.my/api/v1/login
> net::ERR_FAILED

So I try to apply this solution like

- add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
- if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
  add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
  add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
  return 204;
  }

It does not work. Would you mind helping me with this issue?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have added these headers to the request you are making, from your site (presumably 159.138.83.48), not to the remote resource you are requesting?  But CORS access has to be allowed by the remote resource - it would not be much of a security feature if it was up to site making the request to decide if it was allowed or not.  If you also control `devapi.trial.com.my`, that is where you should add the relevant headers.  If I've misunderstood, and that is what you are already doing, edit your question and show your code.

Comment: Well, it has noting to do with the code as I have verified it. So i think it is happening in the ubuntu server itself, so could it be that it has something to do with the configuration file within the api as this is happening the api itself. So when i went to check the api for the project is giving the 521 error page. So is there any solution regarding this matter.

Comment: The code that you use to generate the CORS headers on `devapi.trial.com.my` has everything to do with the problem :-)

Comment: So how do you fix this problem? Is there something i need to add in the nginx configuration file or within the cors file within my project or is something i am missing in this project or inside the ubuntu server.

Comment: Maybe if you clarify the questions/points I asked/suggested, ppl could help. Do you control `devapi.trial.com.my`? Where did you add those headers? How did you add them? Edit your question, add details.

Comment: well, i added the headers in the nginx config file, Yes, i control it, i add this header in the location so like:
location / { 
        add_header 
}